# Who repaired the window in the Raccoon City Police Department between RE3 and RE2?

Tags: resident-evil-3-nemesis, resident-evil-series, resident-evil-2-1998

Jill was supposedly in the police department before Leon and Claire arrived in town, yet the window Nemesis broke was somehow repaired in *RE2*, so did somebody come along and fix the window while zombies were running rampant in the city?

Comment: Then again based on journal entries in the remakes, I guess it's not unreasonable to think someone would be dumb enough to prioritize fixing a window over leaving town